# Input Mask as TextField in MUI with React Hook Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm trying to use the `TextInput` component from MUI in combination with the MaskInput component from `react-input-mask` and `react-hook-form`. Everything seems to be working fine, but I'm getting an error message in the console about using refs. I've tried using the `useRef` hook and directly selecting the second input, as well as registering the input using the `useEffect` hook, but the error persists. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

> react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of InputElement2 which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference.

```js
import { useFormContext, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { Grid, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import InputMask from "react-input-mask";

const FormInputMask = ({ name, label }) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext();

  return (
    <Grid item xs={12}>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={name}
        defaultValue=""
        render={({ field }) => (
          <InputMask
            {...field}
            maskChar=""
            mask="999 999"
            label={label}
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth={true}
          >
            {(inputProps) => (
              <TextField {...inputProps} />
            )}
          </InputMask>
        )}
      />
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default FormInputMask;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeath, have this problem too with this package. I just tend to ignore this.

But there are ways to remove this problem.

1. Remove React.StrictMode from your app (not quite the fix, but error will dissapear).
2. There is a fork https://github.com/comigotech/react-input-mask, it seems the problem has been fixed, but i didn't tried it myself, can't vouch for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  React.StrictMode is not I was looking for but I'll do my best to find a solution :)